# When I print a Map in Flutter, double quotes are missing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have a **Map** in flutter

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  'key1': 'Dog',
  'key2': 'Chicken',
};
print(map);
```

**Actual Result**

```
{
  key1: Dog,
  key2: Chicken
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
  "key1": "Dog",
  "key2": "Chicken"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any of the following approaches.

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  'key1': 'Dog',
  'key2': 'Chicken',
};
  
print(json.encode(map)); //approach - 1
print(JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(map)); //approach - 2
```

Note: don't forget to import `dart:convert`.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you.

you can Used **`JsonEncoder-class`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/JsonEncoder-class.html)

Refer **`jsonEncode`** function [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'key1': 'Dog',
    'key2': 'Chicken',
  };

  print(JsonEncoder().convert(map));
}
```

Your result:

```
{ 
  "key1":"Dog",
  "key2":"Chicken"
}
```

Comment: `json.encode` is already mentioned by someone else. Please don't use their solution. Thanks

Comment: It's better to use `json.encode(map)` instead of directly using `JsonEncode().convert` because the former call delegates to the later.

Answer (score 1):

The right way of doing it is using Dart's `inspect()` function as shown here:

```dart
import 'dart:developer' as devtools show inspect;

const map = {
  'key1': 'Dog',
  'key2': 'Chicken',
};

void testIt() {
  devtools.inspect(map);
}
```